# Excel trick: pasting an entire column

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I have a list of postal codes. I want to paste them into Excel in such
a way that they appear all in one column (which is not the first column).
Can this be done?

If so than in what format should the postal codes be so
that they are pasted vertically, one cell at a time, rather than horizontally.

Furthermore, I would also like to know whether the same trick is possible in
OpenOffice Calc as well.

Comment: note that you can use the `Data>Convert` functions of Excel to split your postal codes and then transpose them (`Copy>Pase Special>Check Transpose`to change from horizontal to vertical)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do so surely..just format them like this in notepad..

```
110085
23485
23473
110001
```

and paste at the desired location in excel..

Answer (score 0):

Just format your postal codes like that:

```
12341
12342
12343
12344
```

then select everything and paste it into the first cell in excel.

Do you need help formatting the postal codes? You can use regular expressions or search & replace in notepad++ to achieve the needed format.

I have not tested it, but it should work in OpenOffice Calc as well!